# how to trigger form validation in angularjs programmatically on a dirty field

Tags: angularjs

I'm setting some form values on an angular form and need to have the validation trigger/set the field to dirty programmatically.  The current bug requires the user to actually interact with the form field to trigger the "required" validation and to have it turn green.

```
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function(response) {
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
        FB.api('/me', function(response) {
      var scope = angular.element($("#PhotoUploadForm")).scope();
      scope.$apply(function(){
        scope.user.firstName = response.first_name;
        scope.user.lastName = response.last_name;
        scope.user.email = response.email;
      });
});
```

And here is the html

```
<form no-validate id="PhotoUploadForm" name='form' action="/uploaded" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" role="form" ng-controller="Controller">
    <div class="col-md-5">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="firstName" >First Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstName" name="firstName" ng-model="user.firstName" required />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label  class="control-label" for="lastName">Last Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastName" name="lastName" ng-model="user.lastName" required />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="email">Email</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" ng-model="user.email" required />
        </div>

    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:form.FormController#methods_$removecontrol

Comment: `angular.element($("#PhotoUploadForm"))` is there a reason for this?  Why wrap the element in jQuery then wrap it in Angular?  angular.element is a subset of jQuery in and of itself.

Comment: I'm actually calling the update function in a facebook javascript event handler.. the form fields get set from a facebook connect.. I've added the facebook event to the question for clarity

Comment: if I wanted to call $setDirty, where should I call it from/on.  I tried Controller.$setDirty() as well as scope.$setDirty() but that didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it this way:
`angular.element('#PhotoUploadForm').scope().user.firstName.$dirty = true`

Let me know if it helps.